# No need for code signing with Xcode 7 for developers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

If there is no need or code signing with Xcode 7 for developers then how it can achieved with xcode 7 realease.

As its still showing error : `CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 9.0'`

**It is possible or not?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Launch your application on devices using free provisioning (iOS, watchOS)**

1. In Xcode, add your Apple ID to Accounts preferences, described in [Adding Your Apple ID Account in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingAccounts/ManagingAccounts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH24-SW2).
   [image]
2. In the project navigator, select the project and your target to display the project editor.
3. Click General and choose your name from the Team pop-up menu.
   [image]
4. Now click on Fix Issue

@Thats it done. I have tested in Objective-C Project. **@Adithya** : Thank you for your contribution

Answer (score 7):

Found this [Apple Docs link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH27-SW3). Make sure you have followed these steps.

I believe currently it only works with Swift.

Comment: As i have followed the steps, was successful in doing it.